# Xcode 6, iOS 8, Cocoa Touch Framework Bi directional frameworks / cyclic dependency error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode6, ios-universal-framework

My first time to post in here. Can't find any answer anywhere on my question. Please anyone:

I used earlier the iOS-Universal-Framework / fake framework to build two **big** frameworks, that depends of each other. So f.x. just to clarify:

Framework 1  (F1) has class A, B, C, ... 
Framework 2  (F2) has class D, E, F, ...

So, what I normally did was to:  
1) compile **F1** with a global macro 'ENABLE_**F2**_METHODS_AND_TYPES' = 0  
2) then moved to **F2** and compiled **F2** similarly with a macro 'ENABLE_**F1**_METHODS_AND_TYPES' = 0  
Now both framework exists with class, types, etc.  
3) compile **F1** with macro = 1  
4) compile **F2** with macro = 1

That was all.

Now, the iOS-Universal-Framework is deprecated, and I have decided to move the frameworks into Cocoa Touch frameworks. So, at this moment, I have two Touch frameworks, but if I try to do similar approach, I successfully compile the two first steps, but not the third step.

I try to do some different attempts but didn't succeed.

I get the error:

***Cannot find interface declaration for 'B' superclass of 'D';***

so, what I tried is to add the `#import "<F1/B.h>"`, but then get the error

***Cyclic dependency in module 'F2': F2 -> F1 -> F2***

How to solve this? Any other ideas?

---

IF succeeded, how to avoid that the frameworks is not going to be integrated into each other (Umbrella framework), but standalone frameworks.  What I mean, in the

'Project' -> General -> 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' -> I can choose "Required/Optional'.... Will that help or?

Thanks in advance.